# Where to find documentation for apple services (agents, daemons) and status codes?

Tags: launchd, daemons, macos

I have looked all over the place with incredible frustration - what should be basic information I can't find anywhere. Whatever I do find, is single items of information (and not what I was looking for).

Instead of poking for info on a case by case basis, is there one or a few main reference documents that will give all the info for Apples services (along with there codes)? Also, perhaps something similar for the major, popular 3rd party services?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try typing `man launchd` into Terminal?

Comment: Don't see any relevant information there. Where the Launch* files are is good info though.

Comment: fwiw I found this http://macinside.info/browse.php but seems to lack a lot of info. a wannabe wiki I suppose